# Dimension reduction for discrete qualitative and aggregated variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, dataset, dimensionality-reduction, contingency-tables

I know about PCA for multiple dimensions of continuous features but here is a problem I have some trouble to find a method for.

I don't have a list of individual countries but rather a discrete classification of countries, and for each line (which I'll call *segments*) I have two output variables.

Each line can represent one or several countries, as long as they fit all the classifications of this particular line. In case a line represents several countries, then the output variables are total values (in case of a number like total population) or pondered averages (in case of a percentage like employment rate).

[image: Data table excerpt]

**So my questions are:**

- Does this particular way of organising data have a name?
- How can I isolate the most influential dimensions for, say, Employment rate? (aka discriminant analysis)
- How can I perform something similar to PCA with this discrete classification instead of continuous values as dimension values?

Comment: It is "aggregated data": rather than a row it is a country, a row is a class of countries, the class being defined by a combination by of levels of 5 attributes.

Comment: You could do a regression (for employment rate, in would be probably Poisson regression). You could also do loglinear analyses (with total population in cells), and to display graphically associations between the levels of the attributes in this 5D frequency table you might do multiple correspondence analysis (as a substitute for PCA).

Comment: Discriminant analysis is not probably what you mean or need, it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @ttnphns thanks - doesn't MCA need a Burt Table or a Complete Disjunctive Table to be performed on?

Comment: Good question. It completely depends on the program you use. Algorithmically, analysing the second (dummies) is what usually done in MCA. But the input could be any allowed by the program.

Comment: @ttnphns FWIW I'm using Python - the goal is to do automated analysis on-demand for lots of different sets of data. I was thinking of programmatically reconstituting the graphs (like, total population by employment rate intervals) and analysing and combining them. Perhaps there are better and less computationally expensive ways though.

Comment: I feel uneasy like having gastroscopy or other intubation when they say about (too much) "automated analysis".

Comment: @ttnphns you definitely have a point - but what if a certain part of analysis could be "automated" in some way just to allow human-analysers to focus on the most interesting part of the work? Would it unrealistic in your opinion?

Comment: My personal opinion: one is warranted to use any highly automated task - if he can at least explain the theory and operations behind it, if not program it himself.